# Building a kernel patch: Error MODPOST 0

Tags: linux, git, build, linux-kernel

I used git to clone the linux repo. From there I branched and edited a file. Now when trying to build using

```
make M=path/to/directory
```

I get the error:

> Building modules, stage 2. MODPOST 0 modules

I have been googling for hours trying to make sure my menuconfig is set up so modules are included, I have tried copying my own config into the git directory, I have tried make clean and modules_install. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

By default, kbuild doesn't create modules. For build modules you need to specify corresponding **target** for make:

```
make M=path/to/directory modules
```